# Computing abelianizations of some explict finite subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, finite-groups

I have been attempting to find some abelianizations of some subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})$. I have been using brute force for the most part but I get very messy results. Here is an example:

---

Let $H = \left\lbrace \left( \begin{matrix}
a & b \epsilon \\ 
b & a
\end{matrix} \right), \left( \begin{matrix}
a & b \epsilon \\ 
-b & -a
\end{matrix} \right) \right\rbrace$, then compute $[H,H]$:

$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \epsilon \\
 b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \epsilon \\
 y & x \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \epsilon \\
 b & a \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \epsilon \\
 y & x \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) $

$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \epsilon \\
 -b & -a \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \epsilon \\
 -y & -x \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \epsilon \\
 -b & -a \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \epsilon \\
 -y & -x \\
\end{array}
\right) $

$ = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{-a^2 t y^2-a^2 x^2+4 a b t x y-b^2 t^2 y^2-b^2 t x^2}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} & \frac{-2 a^2 t x y+2 a b t^2 y^2+2 a b t x^2-2 b^2 t^2 x y}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} \\
\frac{-2 a^2 x y+2 a b t y^2+2 a b x^2-2 b^2 t x y}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} & \frac{-a^2 t y^2-a^2 x^2+4 a b t x y-b^2 t^2 y^2-b^2 t x^2}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right) $

$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \epsilon \\
 b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \epsilon \\
 -y & -x \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \epsilon \\
 b & a \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \epsilon \\
 -y & -x \\
\end{array}
\right) $

$ = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{(b x-a y) (-b t x-a t y)+(-a x-b t y) (a x-b t y)}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} & \frac{(b t y-a x) (-b t x-a t y)+(a t y-b t x) (-a x-b t y)}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} \\
 \frac{(a x+b t y) (b x-a y)+(b x+a y) (a x-b t y)}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} & \frac{(a t y-b t x) (b x+a y)+(b t y-a x) (a x+b t y)}{\left(a^2-b^2 t\right) \left(t y^2-x^2\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right) $

---

So I would like to know if there is a better way of computing abelianizations of these sorts of groups? Or if it is done already for the groups I am interested in? The other subgroups I need abelianizations for are $ \left\lbrace \left( \begin{matrix}
a & bp^{s-1} \\ 
cp^s & d
\end{matrix} \right) \right\rbrace $ & $ \left\lbrace \left( \begin{matrix}
a & bp^r \\ 
cp^r & d
\end{matrix} \right) \right\rbrace $. Thanks